# getting black screen on windows when laucnh my kivy app

Tags: android, python, kivy

im still a begginer with kivy, when i launch my kivy app on windows i get a black winodw and the window fits the whole laptop screen. how can i fix this and how can i resize the window?

my python code

```
# File name FaceRecognition.py
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

# Define each screen

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


Builder.load_file("facerecognition.kv")

class FaceRecognitionApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()

if __name__=="__main__":
    FaceRecognitionApp().run()
```

my kv file

```
# File name FaceRecognition.kv
#: kivy 1.9.1


ScreenManagement:
    id: screen_management
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:


<MyButton@Button>:

    color: .8,.9,0,1    # yellow color
    font_size: 32 # font size
    size_hint: .2,.1

<ScreenOne>:
    name: "screen1"
    id: screen_one

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text:"Hello\n Welcome to my App\n"
            font_size:40 
            color: 0,0,0,1
        MyButton:
            text: 'Next'
            pos_hint:{'right':1, 'y':0}
            on_press:root.manager.current="screen2"

<ScreenOne>:
    name: "screen2"
    id: screen_two

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text:"Please insert your Name\n Please insert your Password\n"
            font_size:40 
            color: 0,0,0,1
        MyButton:
            text: 'Next'
            pos_hint:{'right':1, 'y':0}
            on_press:root.manager.current="screen1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- first of all you are defining `<ScreenOne>` twice in your kv file, second one should be `<ScreenTwo>`
- you are defining a root widget by returning it in your build method. you are also defining it in your kv file by not putting `<>` around it. You need to get rid of one definition. I just put it in `<>` in the kv file.
- your labels color is black, hence black on black, you won't see anything. I changed it to white `color: 1,1,1,1`
- the window does not fill up the whole screen on my Laptop. I think this is not a code issue.

Here is the kv file with all the changes I mentioned in the list. It works on my pc.

```
# File name FaceRecognition.kv
#: kivy 1.9.1


<ScreenManagement>:
    id: screen_management
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:


<MyButton@Button>:

    color: .8,.9,0,1    # yellow color
    font_size: 32 # font size
    size_hint: .2,.1

<ScreenOne>:
    name: "screen1"
    id: screen_one

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text:"Hello\n Welcome to my App\n"
            font_size:40 
            color: 1,1,1,1
        MyButton:
            text: 'Next'
            pos_hint:{'right':1, 'y':0}
            on_press:root.manager.current="screen2"

<ScreenTwo>:
    name: "screen2"
    id: screen_two

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text:"Please insert your Name\n Please insert your Password\n"
            font_size:40 
            color: 1,1,1,1
        MyButton:
            text: 'Next'
            pos_hint:{'right':1, 'y':0}
            on_press:root.manager.current="screen1"
```